# How to write coffee-script and sass in Rhodes / RhoMobile?

Tags: coffeescript, sass, rhomobile, rhodes

I would like to write sass and coffee-script code in Rhodes/RhoMobile and let the compiler automatically compile to js and css file before `run` or `build` task, for every platforms I am targeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example you place your sass files in assets/stylesheets directory. Processed and compressed files will output in public/css. This also preserve the sub directory structure

An error during compilation will stop the process

Adjust the before hook depending on the platform your are targetting

Add this task at then very end of your Rakefile:

```
task :precompile_css do
  Dir.chdir $app_path do
    exit_code = system 'scss --force --update assets/stylesheets:public/css --style compressed'
    raise 'Precompile error' unless exit_code
  end
end

# Add all platforms you need.
# To get the exact name of the task to hook you can execute 
# $ rake -n run:my_platform
task 'config:android' => :precompile_css
task 'config:wm' => :precompile_css
etc ...
```

Also possible with coffeescript

```
task :precompile_js do
  Dir.chdir $app_path do
    exit_code = system 'coffee --compile --output public/js/ assets/javascripts/'
    raise 'Precompile error' unless exit_code
  end
end

task 'config:android' => :precompile_js
task 'config:wm' => :precompile_js
etc...
```

Then just invoke your `run` or `build` tasks as usual